# Getting error on SQL query: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting below error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

when making the query:

```
Select  guid,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEADD(day,30,U73_SCANDATE)) as scan 
from emp;
```

`U73_SCANDATE` data type is varchar, and its like

```
26-NOV-08 01.00.00.000000000 PM
```

How can I convert this to datetime and use `dateadd` properly?

Comment: Delete this question.  Ask another question and try to explain why you are using SQL Server syntax in a question tagged MySQL.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Below is my select statement:
SELECT ID,DATEADD(day,30,U73_SCANDATE) as DATE from EMP

Below is the error i am getting :
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Select guid,dateadd(DAY,10,U73_SCANDATE) as scan1 from EMP

Comment: I don't think your U73_SCANDATE has a correct date format

Comment: Its data type is varchar, and its like "26-NOV-08 01.00.00.000000000 PM"

Comment: Do you need date precision down to the billionths of a second? If his is SQL Server, a datetime datatype only goes to 3 digits after the decimal. Datetime2 can go further if you need it. If that's your varchar string, SQL won't know how to convert that to a datetime. Remove some of the decimals and it should work.

Comment: How is this date being generated or where is it coming from?

Comment: CORRECTION: A datetime2 only goes to 7 digits after the decimal, so you'll need to trim off some of the extra digits before you'll be able to implicitly convert and dateAdd().

Comment: We are migrating data from one to db to another, pls tell me how to trim last 0000 part

Comment: @SharathN have you seen my answer?

Comment: @gofr1 How can i use this in java? by declaring variable?

Comment: No, you can do this in your select query, variable declaration just for testing and showing output.

Comment: @gofr1 pls let me know how to use?

Comment: @SharathN I add this to my answer.

Comment: @gofr1 Thank u so much:) Great work

Comment: @SharathN My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to use some weird stuff to get this as datetime:

```
DECLARE @U73_SCANDATE varchar(50) = '26-NOV-08 01.00.00.000000000 PM'

SELECT  CAST(
            --This part replaces - with spaces and add 20 to year part 
            STUFF(REPLACE(LEFT(@U73_SCANDATE,9),'-',' '),8,0,'20') +                
            --Here we change . to : in a time part
            REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@U73_SCANDATE,10,10),'.',':') +  
            --Take first 3 digits of miliseconds
            LEFT(RIGHT(@U73_SCANDATE,12),3)+
            --And PM/AM part
            RIGHT(@U73_SCANDATE,2)
                as datetime)
```

Output:

```
2008-11-26 13:00:00.000
```

**EDIT**

To use directly on your table:

```
SELECT  guid,
        CAST(
        --This part replaces - with spaces and add 20 to year part 
        STUFF(REPLACE(LEFT(U73_SCANDATE,9),'-',' '),8,0,'20') +                
        --Here we change . to : in a time part
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(U73_SCANDATE,10,10),'.',':') +  
        --Take first 3 digits of miliseconds
        LEFT(RIGHT(U73_SCANDATE,12),3)+
        --And PM/AM part
        RIGHT(U73_SCANDATE,2)
            as datetime) as scan 
from emp;
```